# Magento 2: How to Create "home" link in category

Tags: category, magento2.3

My Magento version is 2.3, **I want to create "home" and "about" link in the category,** I search few articles but it is for Magento 2.0 version, I was not able to find for Magento 2.3 version. **I want first Home, About then categories.**

https://www.marketplace.jawadditaksal.org/

Comment: Try this.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230923/magento-2-how-to-add-home-link-in-navigation-bar

Comment: No it is not working as it says Create registration.php file and add the file to - app/code/Magenik/NavLink/registration.php but in the 2.3 version there is no "code" folder in the "app" folder.

Comment: You have to need create same folder if not exists.

Comment: I follow the article, but nothing work for me.

Comment: @KirtiNariya can you please suggest me for 2.3, non of article work for me

Comment: What error are you facing.

Comment: @KirtiNariya nothing happens after implementation of this, even I clear the cache and refresh the page, no error comes, nothing happens

Comment: share your code files as you was tried.

Comment: see first as in the article says : Create registration file:  registration.php  - look jpg image - https://ibb.co/YfsGCtY   second app/code/Magenik/NavLink/etc/module.xml

Comment: see first as in the article says : Create registration file:  registration.php  - look jpg image - https://ibb.co/YfsGCtY   second app/code/Magenik/NavLink/etc/module.xml - https://ibb.co/XstB8sd third it says app/code/Magenik/NavLink/etc/frontend/di.xml  https://ibb.co/DKQqkdB in the last it says top menu app/code/Magenik/NavLink/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php  https://ibb.co/dBsM6Pd @KirtiNariya

Comment: Your follow steps is right.

Comment: @KirtiNariya then why Home and about is not coming on the menu?, is this the problem that it is 2.3 version

Comment: Yes may be it cause of 2.3 version

Comment: @KirtiNariya please tell me the solution

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @KirtiNariya no it still does not work even I clear the cache via putty

Comment: @KirtiNariya waiting for your reply Madam :)

Answer (score 0):

the lines below in a template that suits where you want these links to appear will show 2 links to go to **About us** page and to **Home page**

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('about-us'); ?>"><?php echo __('About'); ?></a>
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>"><?php echo __('Home'); ?></a>
```

Comment: Where exactly I need to add these code ?

Comment: Sorry mate, I retired from Magento stackexchange until we use a better reviewing system. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to create any category for this.

You need to add this link via code. At Magento, the *menu link has been generated* from `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` and `_getHtml()` is give main *content of the menu*.

So, create `plugin`on  this class  and use before plugin over `_getHtml()`

**1. create di.xml where we will define the plugin.** File location app\code{VendorName}{ModuleName}\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_cms_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. Assume that about us as cms page.Then create the plugin class where we will add a cms page link to the menu.**

```
  <?php 
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
class Topmenu
{
    protected $nodeFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {

        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'name' => __('Home')
                    'id' =>  ''home,
                    'url' =>  $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(),
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' =>  -10,
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }
        /* Showing  Cms page About us at menu */
        $page = $this->getCmspage('about-us');
        if($page == null){
            return;
        }


        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'name' => $page->getTitle(),
                    'id' => $page->getIdentifier(),
                    'url' =>  $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(null, ['_direct' => $page->getIdentifier()]),
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' => -9,
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }
    protected function getCmspage($identifier){

        $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        if (!$pageId) {
            return null;
        }
        $page->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        if (!$page->load($pageId)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$page->getId()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $page;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact location of Di.xml file, is it app/code/Magenik/NavLink/etc/frontend/di.xml and what should be the location of menu and file name for the menu, is it app/code/Magenik/NavLink/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php ?

Comment: So What I did is now I add the di.xml file into the location - app/code/Magenik/NavLink/etc/frontend/di.xml and topmenu.php file into the location  app/code/Magenik/NavLink/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php but still it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction for create top **Home and About** menu before category.

Find below file path in your theme directory and update code. If not exists same path then create same file path and add topmenu.phtml and put below code.

**File path:**

> magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<?php
    $currentUrl = $block->getCurrentUrl();
    $baseUrl = $this->getUrl();
?>

<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>

        <li class="level0 home <?php if($currentUrl == '/'): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>" title="<?php echo __('Home') ?>" class="level-top"><span>Home</span></a></li>

        <li class="level0 <?php if($currentUrl == '/about-us'): ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $baseUrl.'about-us'; ?>" title="<?php echo __('About') ?>" class="level-top"><span>About</span></a></li>

        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_menu ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Let me know if any query.

Hope it help!

Comment: no it still does not work even I clear the cache via putty